# Regex on multiple lines of random order

Tags: javascript, regex, birt

I am using BIRT to design a report based on a database, and one of the fields of the form contain multiple lines, like that :

> Site: Place ThePlace
>
> Room: D2 RMD3
>
> InstanceId: OI-RandomChars

The fact is, they are not always in this order, as it is user input (in an other form, not BIRT prompt).
And please note that these fields contain capital letters.

So what I want to do is to extract in three separate columns, so with three regex in JavaScript the Site, the Room, and the InstanceId.
I have tried many things with like catching each row until the end of the line or playing around substrings with various conditions ... and so far I think the best to do is to use string function replace to remove anything different than what I want to catch.
An example for the row Room would be :

```
row["Log"].replace(/?![Room:\s\S*\s]/, "")
```

I get an error with this but you can see what I try to do.

Thanks for all the consideration about my problem.

Comment: You could `row["Log"].split("\n")` and then test to see which array item has Room/Site/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single regex can become overly complicated and hard to read and mantain for this kind of job.

I would probably consider doing it programmatically like your first instinct was.

First I would consider splitting the string into lines

```
var lines = string.split("\n\n");
```

This will split all your double lines into an array

```
["Site: Place ThePlace", "Room: D2 RMD3", "InstanceId: OI-RandomChars"]
```

Then cycle trough all your lines and then make your checks.
Your check now can actually be regex if you want, or using substring.

This is an example:

```
var site, room, InstanceId;
var siteCheckRegex = new Regex("^Site:");

for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++){

      if(siteCheckRegex.test(lines[i])){
        site = lines[i].replace("Site:","");
      }

      [...]
}
```

It actually depends on what you really want to get out of it and the problem and difference you can find in the user input data.